# jxPath Getting an Object from a list based on value in a Map

Tags: java, jxpath

So I have an object Structure like the following:

I have a Person Object which has a list of Friends (named friends in Person)
 - That list of Friends has a Map (named information)
 - The map has a Key of 'age' and a value of an string

So I am looking to return one Friend where the age of that friend is equal to lets say 20

```
public class Person {
    private List<Friend> friends;

    public List<Friend> getFriends() {
        return friends;
    }

    public void setFriends(List<Friend> friends) {
        this.friends = friends;
    }
}


public class Friend {
    private Map<String, Object> information;

    public Map<String, Object> getInformation() {
        return information;
    }

    public void setInformation(Map<String, Object> information) {
        this.information = information;
    }
}
```

Here is what I was thinking but couldn't get it to work please let me know if I am missing something

```
Friend match = (Friend)JXPathContext.newContext(personInput).getValue("friends/information[@name='age' = '20']//friend");
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to select all the objects under the "friends" link that have an information map that contains an "age" equals to 20. Then you only want the first result.

```
Friend match = (Friend)JXPathContext.newContext(personInput).getValue("friends[information/age = '20'][1]");
```